# Pyqt5 Qt Designer Problem with Back button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm new and i need help. I what to have a function back bottun for return to the main page. I going to include the code of the two windows so please give me a hand.

Main.py

```
import sys    
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Registrati import Ui_RegistratiWindows

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def openWindow(self):
            self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            self.ui = Ui_RegistratiWindows()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            MainWindow.hide()
            self.window.show()
def showLabel(self):
    self.labeltestohelp.show()
    self.labeltestohelp1.show()

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = Ui_RegistratiWindows()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.destroy()
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
    MainWindow.resize(222, 585)
    MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(222, 585))
    MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(222, 585))
    MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
    MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
    MainWindow.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.TabFocus)
    MainWindow.setStatusTip("")
    MainWindow.setWhatsThis("")
    MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
    MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.LoginBotton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.LoginBotton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 201, 51))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("loginicon-png.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.LoginBotton.setIcon(icon)
    self.LoginBotton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
    self.LoginBotton.setAutoDefault(False)
    self.LoginBotton.setObjectName("LoginBotton")
    self.RegistratiBotton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.RegistratiBotton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 280, 201, 51))
    icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("RegisterIcon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.RegistratiBotton.setIcon(icon1)
    self.RegistratiBotton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
    self.RegistratiBotton.setObjectName("RegistratiBotton")

    self.RegistratiBotton.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)

    self.Esci = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.Esci.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 510, 61, 31))
    icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exit-icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.Esci.setIcon(icon2)
    self.Esci.setObjectName("Esci")
    self.labelImag = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.labelImag.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 221, 121))
    self.labelImag.setText("")
    self.labelImag.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("TopImage.png"))
    self.labelImag.setScaledContents(True)
    self.labelImag.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.labelImag.setWordWrap(False)
    self.labelImag.setObjectName("labelImag")
    self.InfoButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.InfoButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 390, 61, 51))
    icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Info.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
    self.InfoButton.setIcon(icon3)
    self.InfoButton.setObjectName("InfoButton")

    self.InfoButton.clicked.connect(self.showLabel)

    self.labeltestohelp = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.labeltestohelp.setEnabled(False)
    self.labeltestohelp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 201, 41))
    self.labeltestohelp.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WhatsThisCursor))
    self.labeltestohelp.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
    self.labeltestohelp.setWordWrap(True)
    self.labeltestohelp.setIndent(10)
    self.labeltestohelp.setObjectName("labeltestohelp")
    self.labeltestohelp.hide()
    self.labeltestohelp1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.labeltestohelp1.setEnabled(False)
    self.labeltestohelp1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 201, 41))
    self.labeltestohelp1.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WhatsThisCursor))
    self.labeltestohelp1.setMouseTracking(False)
    self.labeltestohelp1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
    self.labeltestohelp1.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
    self.labeltestohelp1.setWordWrap(True)
    self.labeltestohelp1.setIndent(18)
    self.labeltestohelp1.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
    self.labeltestohelp1.setObjectName("labeltestohelp1")
    self.labeltestohelp1.hide()
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 222, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "E-Learning"))
    self.LoginBotton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login"))
    self.RegistratiBotton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Registrati"))
    self.Esci.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Esci"))
    self.InfoButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Info"))
    self.labeltestohelp.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Info: Usa Login se sei già Registrato!"))
    self.labeltestohelp1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Info: Registrati per Accedere ai contenuti"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and the second windows Registrati.py

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Domanda import Ui_Infowindows


class Ui_RegistratiWindows(object):
    def Indietro(self):
        os.system("py Main.py")

    def showLabel(self):
        self.labeltestohelp.show()
        self.labeltestohelp1.show()
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.show()
    def setupUi(self, RegistratiWindows):
        RegistratiWindows.setObjectName("RegistratiWindows")
        RegistratiWindows.resize(222, 585)
        RegistratiWindows.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(222, 585))
        RegistratiWindows.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(222, 585))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(RegistratiWindows)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.labelImag = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelImag.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 111, 101))
        self.labelImag.setText("")
        self.labelImag.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("img_504963.png"))
        self.labelImag.setScaledContents(True)
        self.labelImag.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.labelImag.setWordWrap(False)
        self.labelImag.setObjectName("labelImag")
        self.labelTitolo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelTitolo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 221, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gill Sans MT")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.labelTitolo.setFont(font)
        self.labelTitolo.setScaledContents(False)
        self.labelTitolo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelTitolo.setObjectName("labelTitolo")
        self.lineEditUsername = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEditUsername.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(12, 190, 201, 20))
        self.lineEditUsername.setObjectName("lineEditUsername")
        self.lineEditUsername_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEditUsername_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 201, 20))
        self.lineEditUsername_2.setObjectName("lineEditUsername_2")
        self.labelusername = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelusername.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 101, 16))
        self.labelusername.setObjectName("labelusername")
        self.labelusername_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelusername_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 270, 101, 16))
        self.labelusername_2.setObjectName("labelusername_2")
        self.InfoButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.InfoButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 390, 61, 51))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Info.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
        self.InfoButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.InfoButton.setObjectName("InfoButton")

        self.InfoButton.clicked.connect(self.showLabel)

        self.Esci_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Esci_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 510, 61, 31))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exit-icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
        self.Esci_2.setIcon(icon1)
        self.Esci_2.setObjectName("Esci_2")
        self.labeltestohelp = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labeltestohelp.setEnabled(False)
        self.labeltestohelp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 220, 201, 41))
        self.labeltestohelp.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WhatsThisCursor))
        self.labeltestohelp.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.labeltestohelp.setWordWrap(True)
        self.labeltestohelp.setIndent(15)
        self.labeltestohelp.setObjectName("labeltestohelp")
        self.labeltestohelp.hide()
        self.labeltestohelp1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labeltestohelp1.setEnabled(False)
        self.labeltestohelp1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 320, 201, 41))
        self.labeltestohelp1.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WhatsThisCursor))
        self.labeltestohelp1.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.labeltestohelp1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.labeltestohelp1.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.labeltestohelp1.setWordWrap(True)
        self.labeltestohelp1.setIndent(18)
        self.labeltestohelp1.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.labeltestohelp1.setObjectName("labeltestohelp1")
        self.labeltestohelp1.hide()
        self.labeltestohelp1_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 390, 81, 81))
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WhatsThisCursor))
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setWordWrap(True)
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setIndent(8)
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setObjectName("labeltestohelp1_3")
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.hide()
        self.RegButtun = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.RegButtun.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 390, 61, 61))
        self.RegButtun.setText("Registrati")
        self.RegButtun.setObjectName("RegButtun")
        self.IndietroButtun = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.IndietroButtun.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 480, 61, 61))
        self.IndietroButtun.setText("Back")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("back.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
        self.IndietroButtun.setIcon(icon2)
        self.IndietroButtun.setObjectName("IndietroButtun")

        self.IndietroButtun.clicked.connect(self.Indietro)

        RegistratiWindows.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(RegistratiWindows)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 222, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        RegistratiWindows.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(RegistratiWindows)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        RegistratiWindows.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(RegistratiWindows)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(RegistratiWindows)

    def retranslateUi(self, RegistratiWindows):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        RegistratiWindows.setWindowTitle(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Registrati"))
        self.labelTitolo.setText(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Registra il tuo volto"))
        self.labelusername.setText(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Username:"))
        self.labelusername_2.setText(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Password:"))
        self.InfoButton.setText(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Info"))
        self.Esci_2.setText(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Esci"))
        self.labeltestohelp.setText(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Info: Inserisci il tuo Username che verra usato per identificarti"))
        self.labeltestohelp1.setText(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Info: Inserisci la tua Password per accedere ai tuoi contenuti"))
        self.labeltestohelp1_3.setText(_translate("RegistratiWindows", "Info: Clicca su Registrati per far iniziare la fase di registrazione del tuo volto"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    RegistratiWindows = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_RegistratiWindows()
    ui.setupUi(RegistratiWindows)
    RegistratiWindows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So whit this two windows i can manage to open from Main.py->Registrati.py but when i want to return to the main windows i can use os.system() (brutaly but works) but the Registrati windows remains open in the background. So pleas gime me same tips for colsing the Registrati windows. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do (do you  want to run two separate applications or `Registrati.py` is simply a dialog to be open by `Main.py` ?) there are two solutions:

1. the first solution is to make `Registrati.py` a dialog so from the `Main.py` you don't run a complete application and your `Back button` is nothing more than the `Close` button of the dialog.
2. the second solution is to connect the `Back button` to the `quit()` slot of the appplication launched by `Registrati.py`, this way you close the second application and have only the firse one still running.

Comment: Run two separate applications it seems the bettere solution. Just because i can apply the same solution on the future windows i want to make. Can you give me how to do it? please?

Comment: I don't agree that two separate application is a better solution but it is your call ;-). Anyway, try to change the line `self.IndietroButtun.clicked.connect(self.Indietro)` in the `Registrati.py` with this `self.IndietroButtun.clicked.connect(self.close)`. This should close the window opened by `Registrati.py`

Comment: @MicheleSpedalieri No, it is not appropriate to have different applications, for example let's say you want to transfer data from the first window to the second one, how would you do with your current methodology? That is a kind of problems, we could list other problems, so that you thought smells like a bad design,

Comment: Yeah i tried to use **self. close** inside the **Indietro** function and the window stay open, and just open the Main.py, if i do such you suggest i just clese the **Registrati** window without open the **Main** window.        There is a way to open back the main window and simply close the Registrati window?